# Callback identification in superpowered

Tags: ios, superpowered

I'm trying to extend a piece of code that uses the `SuperPowered` audio library in an iOS application. In particular, I'm interested in the `void playerEventCallback(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void *value)`callback, which gets passed a pointer to the managing SuperPowered object when the audio player is created:

> ```
> SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerCallback callback, unsigned int sampleRate, unsigned char cachedPointCount, unsigned int internalBufferSizeSeconds = 2, unsigned int negativeSeconds = 0);
> ```

If I understand the code right, nothing prevents me from modifying this situation for my own purpose, passing, for example, a pointer to an object in an array, which would identify the player that is/was running, instead of the managing SuperPowered object.

Can I do that, or is there a consequence I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing exactly that, passing an instance of a struct defined as follows:

```
struct AudioPlayerWithIndex {

    int index;
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer* player;
    Superpowered* superpoweredInstance;

    AudioPlayerWithIndex(int index, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer* player, Superpowered* superpoweredInstance) : index(index), player(player), superpoweredInstance(superpoweredInstance) {}
};
```

Comment: @MiliShah As I remember it, placed directly into the Superpowered.mm file you define, as per the doc. Called where your application needs it...